# How to compare date in nunjucks?

Tags: javascript, html, nunjucks

So I have an array object.

```
var abc = [{ "title": "abc", "validUntil": "9/7/2019"];
```

I'm not sure how to compare date in nunjucks. I also think this can be done in the loop itself.

```
<div>
    {% for a in abc %}
       {% if new Date(offer.validUntil) > new Date() %}
         {{a.title}}
       {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a global function `toDate`

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

// returns `now` if no argument is passed 
env.addGlobal('toDate', function(date) {
    return date ? new Date(date) : new Date();
});

var html = env.renderString(`
        <div>
            {% for offer in offers %}
               {% if toDate(offer.validUntil) > toDate() %}
                 {{offer.title}}
               {% endif %}
             {% endfor %}
        </div>
    `, 
    { 
        offers: [
            {title: 'Some offer title', validUntil: '9/7/2019'},
            {title: 'Another offer title', validUntil: '1/6/2019'}
        ] 
    });

console.log(html);
```

The another way is to define a custom filter `isActual`

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

env.addFilter('isActual', function(offers) {
    return offers.filter(offer => new Date(offer.validUntil) > new Date());
});

var html = env.renderString(
    `
        <div>
            {% for offer in offers | isActual %}
                 {{offer.title}}
             {% endfor %}
        </div>
    `, 
    { 
        offers: [
            {title: 'Some offer title', validUntil: '9/7/2019'},
            {title: 'Another offer title', validUntil: '1/6/2019'}
        ] 
    });

console.log(html);
```

P.S. Pass date is a string like `9/7/2019` is a bad idea. The date intepretation (`dd.mm.yyyy` or `mm.dd.yyyy`) depends on browser setting. I recommend to use unix-epoch: `new Date().getTime()`.